# Committing from multiple machines to single zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

We have solrcloud (with 11 shards on 4 machines, 1 zookeeper). We want to index more than 100 million documents. We are pulling documents from database, preparing xml files and posting them to solrcloud.

As most of the time is spent in preparing xml files, we distributed this task on multiple machines. So, we are preparing xml files on multiple machines and all these machines are posting xml files to same zookeeper (solrcloud)

This solution is working fast for us to prepare xml files but occasionally we are getting an error saying that

503 Service Unavailable: {"responseHeader":{"status":503,"QTime":412},"error":{"msg":"Cannot talk to ZooKeeper - Updates are disabled.","code":503

Having multiple zookeepers will solve this problem ? Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Check this out if you have not yet [ZooKeeper related SolrCloud problems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3274).

Comment: Are there any reason why you have just one zookeeper? That kinda defeats the whole purpose of having ZooKeeper and SolrCloud, as the ZooKeeper handles all the failover magic and metainformation about nodes. How are you indexing? SolrJ is cluster aware through Zookeeper, allowing it to index directly to the correct node.

Comment: There is no specific reason why we have only one zookeeper. We do not know if having multiple zookeepers will improve our indexing & searching time in our case. We also do not know how many zookeepers we should have. We want to figure that our. We are posting xml document to zookeeper node to index.

Answer (score 0):

I too have similar usecase and faced this problem during high volume load. I solved this problem by adding two more additional zookeeper nodes and my **lws-solrcoud has 5** nodes with **5 zookeeper nodes**.
 I would suggest, either you stop ingestion process for sometime or add additional nodes.
Interesting piece of problem is sometimes I get  **"No servers hosting shard exception"** during high volume load and server's shards get recover automatically after sometime. We create client side lock which monitor cloud shards state and all ingestion threads are blocked waiting until lock is released.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: no servers hosting shard:
```

Comment: Thank you for that. _"We create client side lock which monitor cloud shards state and all ingestion threads are blocked waiting until lock is released."_         How do you do that?

Comment: The data ingestion process is developed in java using solrj. When we get solrException, we start new thread which monitor solrcloud state and send ingestion thread sleep until monitor thread notify success state of server. Monitor thread run in infinite loop and internally uses CLUSTERSTATE action and ping command. If monitor thread runs for long time then we stop ingestion process and notify user.